# Update timestamp of files being renamed

Tags: php

I am recursively bulk renaming files in a directory using the rename function (thanks to Markus Zeller for code):

```
 $search = 'image1';
 $replace = 'great';
 $path = '/path/to/files/';
 $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
 foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $file) {
 if ($file->isFile() && str_contains($file->getFilename(), $search)) {
    @rename($file->getPathName(), str_replace($search, $replace, $file->getPathName()));
 }
 }
```

This works great, but the renamed files haven't had their timestamp updated to the current date/time (they retain their original creation date).  I have tried adding the "touch()" command but it instead creates empty files (0 bytes):

```
 touch(@rename($file->getPathName(), str_replace($search, $replace, $file->getPathName())));
```

The reason I need the time of the files changed is because I am renaming cache files and need the creation date to be current.
If anyone has a solution that would be great thanks.

Comment: [`rename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) either returns `true` or `false` and not the path to the file

Comment: I also tried adding this line: touch($file->getPathName());  but that only created the old filenames

Comment: After the rename function, isn't that the new filename?

Comment: OK could you please help me out - in the above example how would I "touch" the newly renamed file?

Comment: Thanks DarkBee, I'll try that out now...

Comment: @Dark is this a duplicate? Why are you posting resolving advice as comments? Please resolve this page in a legitimate manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`rename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) either returns `true` or `false` and not the path to the file, so you can't "shorthand" the code and need to use the *new* filename in order to "`touch`" the correct file.

```
<?php
    $target = str_replace($search, $replace, $file->getPathName());
    rename($file->getPathName(), $target);
    touch($target);
```